# mysql full outer join with group by and table aliases

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Table 1
DATE dt
int  amt

Table 2
DATE dt
int  amt
```

The date column is not unique in each table.  I would like to be able to see sums of each amount for any date which exists in either table like so:

```
date  t1.amt   t2.amt
...
```

Here's as far as I have gotten:

```
select coalesce(t1.dt, t2.dt), t1.amount, t2.amount from 
    (Select dt, sum(amt) from t1 group by dt) As t1
    left join
    (SELECT dt, sum(amt) from t2 group by dt) as t2
    on (t1.dt = t2.dt);
```

Then, everything I try in order to perform a right join (to make complete an outer join) just gives me syntax errors. The problem seems to be with the table aliases.

If anyone could please help me to complete the outer join I would appreciate it.  :)

Thank you for reading this far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `union all` and `group by`:

```
select dt, sum(amt)
from ((select dt, amt from t1) union all
      (select dt, amt from t2)
     ) tt
group by dt;
```

If you want them in separate columns, use two columns:

```
select dt, sum(amt1), sum(amt2)
from ((select dt, amt as amt1, NULL as amt2 from t1) union all
      (select dt, NULL, amt from t2)
     ) tt
group by dt;
```